# How to log in with a server name as (local) in SQL Server and also on the connectionstring?

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server 2014 and I'm kind of new to SQL Server. After installing SQL Server, there is only one instance of SQL Server with my PC's user name. If I try to login in using the SQL Server name as `(local)`, it won't login. But if I use the instance name it logins successfully.

The reason I want to login with this SQL Server name `(local)` is because I don't want to reset the connection string in my ASP team project every time after I made a pull from that project or worse make a push to Git.

Error message:

[image]

Comment: What does "won't login" mean? Do you get an error message? Is your local a named instance? With no details the best we can do is guess.

Comment: Yes my local is a named instance and also yes it shows an error message that says:
Cannot connect to (local).
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct ..........

Comment: The [named vs default instance](http://serverfault.com/a/80771/118848) problem? [More](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b78115e-67fa-4954-9538-5b10f8785965/whats-the-difference-between-installing-a-default-instance-vs-a-named-instance?forum=sqlgetstarted).

Comment: There is no default instance (MSSQLSERVER) created, only the named one. Do you know a way to create one though, default instance?

Comment: You have to install an instance as the default.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server did you install? If you installed SQL Server **Express**, it defaults to a `SQLEXPRESS` instance name, so unless you explicitly changed that during install, you need to connect to it using `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name

Comment: FYI, you cannot use (local) with a named instance, this does not work and never has.  The proper way to handle this is to have your connection string handled externally with config.xml, client aliases, etc.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @RBarryYoung. Do you know any blog that shows how to handle the connection string externally? I would appreciate that.

Comment: Just google "*asp.net web.config connection string*".  Here's the first link, a Microsoft how-to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed the error with a clue given to me by @kstix and @Sean Lang, I installed a new instance as a default (MSSQLSERVER). Now I can log in using the server name (local).

But for best practice like @RBarryYoung suggested 
make the connection string configuration external check out this link for how to:D

[Sql Connection Strings in .Config Files vs. Source Control](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Feb/27/Sql-Connection-Strings-in-Config-Files-vs-Source-Control#ExternalConfigurationSections)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Server 2005 Default and Named Instances](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614(v=sql.90).aspx)

> An instance is either the default, unnamed instance, or it is a named instance. When SQL Server 2005 is in installed in the default instance, it does not require a client to specify the name of the instance to make a connection. The client only has to know the server name.
>
> A named instance is identified by the network name of the computer plus the instance name that you specify during installation. The client must specify both the server name and the instance name when connecting.

**(local) always refers to the default instance.**

Creating aliases is a corner case; not a best practice.

To connect to the default instance without calling it (local), just use the machine name.

**Example:**

```
Default         MYPCNAME
Default         localhost
Default         127.0.0.1
Named instance  MYPCNAME\Foo
Named instance  localhost\Foo
Named instance  127.0.0.1\Foo
```

Comment: You are right. But the whole idea of using the server name (local) was for the connection string to work in every machine that the project runs on. If I used the machine name then the connection string works only on my local project but for others they have to change it to their own machine name which we don't want.

Comment: @ash that is simple, use:   localhost\MyInstanceName  I adited the answer acordingly

Comment: @ash also, that being the case, aliases won't help you, because you would need to manually configure each alias configuration on each machine where SQL Server is running, and your statement implies your are installing SQL Server  (express I assume) on each machine.

Comment: I'm not actually installing SQL servers on different machine. What I'm referring to is to git projects that use the connection strings that I mentioned. If I used the server name (local) and others that are on git project do the same....problem solved.